# Why does my python prompt disappear when changing working directory and importing?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python, and I'm trying to get a basic working understanding of changing the working directory and working with .py files. At the moment, I've changed the directory to where a couple of my .py files are, but when I go to import them, I get a time lag of over a minute for each one. Is that to be expected? Any idea what's going on? Here's what I'm doing:

```
Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:06:53) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'C:\\Python33'
>>> os.chdir("C:/Users/MarketResearch")
>>> import EarningsDownload
>>> import RatingsChanges
>>>
```

Comment: Generally changing the working directory to import stuff is a really bad idea - either add the to your Python path (or place them somewhere in the path), so they can be accessed from anywhere, or put them alongside what you are running. It definitely shouldn't take a minute to import something. (It's also worth noting [PEP-8 recommends `lowercase_with_underscores` for module names](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions)).

Comment: This must be a windows phenomenon. Things imported immediately for me on Ubuntu 12.04 with Python 2.x and 3.x. The files EarningsDownload.py and RatingsChanges.py may actually be executing long running code when imported, which is responsible for the delay.

Comment: @Lattyware Thanks. I'll look into how to change the path.

Comment: @EricUrban You're probably right, I'm coming from C# so I'm not used to automatic execution on import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your module is actually doing work when it is imported.  This is (usually) a bad idea.  What you should do instead is put your setup code into a function, say `setup()` or `initialize()`, and then call it after importing:

```
import earnings_download
earnings_download.initialize()
```